# Blacklist in redux persist not working although blacklist is mentioned within my config

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I have two values which i'd like my redux persist not to work on and not persist , as i read through the docs it seems this is to be achieved through blacklisting , my redux store and config looks like this :

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  FLUSH,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  persistReducer,
  persistStore,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
  REHYDRATE,
} from "redux-persist";
import auth from "./slices/authSlice";
import organizationName from "./slices/organizationNameSlice";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth: auth.reducer,
  organizationName: organizationName.reducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

my auth slice , two of the values i want to be not persisted : the auth slice initial state is :

```
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  error: null,
  isLoading: false,
  refreshToken: null,
  success: null,
};
```

the two values are error and success , if i were to change my persist config to

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  blacklist: ['error']
```

that achieves nothing , any idea what's the correct way to do as the docs aren't very clear to me ?
};

Comment: Can you check the web storage? Does the `error` state persist or not?

Comment: @slideshowp2 it does persist